# product_categories shortcode loop add extra link to category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

Using the woocommerce shortcode:

```
[product_categories number="3" ids="69, 70, 71"]
```

This returns the three categories I have listed. I wish to add an additional link to the category page of each of the returned categories:

```
<?php 
add_action('woocommerce_after_subcategory', 'add_meta_to_cat', 1);

function add_meta_to_cat() { 
?>

    <a class = "cta" href="<?php the_category(); ?>">SHOP NOW</a>

<?php
}
```

This adds the button with a link to the current page.

Do I need to hook into the shortcode loop specifically? 
Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Instead using `the_category();` you will need to use something like:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_subcategory', 'add_meta_to_cat', 1);
function add_meta_to_cat() { 
    $prod_cat_args = array(
        'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
        'orderby'      => 'name',
        'empty'        => 0
    );

    $terms = get_categories( $prod_cat_args );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
        echo '<a class="cta" href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . __( "SHOP NOW", "your_theme_slug" ) . '</a>';
    }
}
```